# how to Display the multiple files array were uploaded by CarrierWave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite, carrierwave

I used gem CarrierWave upload the multiple files and I can upload success, but I can't download and display the address for each one.

I tried to use console display the array of my uploaded file, and I got this:

```
2.2.4 :013 > Legislation.find(14).documents.each do |doc|
2.2.4 :014 >     puts doc
2.2.4 :015?>   end
  Legislation Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "legislations".* FROM "legislations" WHERE "legislations"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 14]]
/uploads/legislation/documents/14/%5B%2267490.jpg%22%2C%20%2214536943_1300076803359446_1963523476_o.jpg%22%2C%20%221436764358456.jpg%22%2C%20%22ch_09b.ppt%22%5D
 => [#<DocumentUploader:0x007fc5c7b6bcc0 @model=#<Legislation id: 14, title: "ascsf", created_at: "2016-11-02 08:51:39", updated_at: "2016-11-02 08:51:39", attachment: nil, documents: "[\"67490.jpg\", \"14536943_1300076803359446_196352347...">, @mounted_as=:documents, @storage=#<CarrierWave::Storage::File:0x007fc5c7b6bbf8 @uploader=#<DocumentUploader:0x007fc5c7b6bcc0 ...>>, @file=#<CarrierWave::SanitizedFile:0x007fc5c7b6b2e8 @file="/Users/ChamperWu/projects/nsysu_mem/public/uploads/legislation/documents/14/[\"67490.jpg\", \"14536943_1300076803359446_1963523476_o.jpg\", \"1436764358456.jpg\", \"ch_09b.ppt\"]", @original_filename=nil, @content_type=nil>, @versions={}>]
```

when I upload one file the address of file is wrong, the file name will be

> %5B%2267490.jpg%22%2C%20%

not real name

> 67490.jpg

Controller:

```
def legislation_params
    params.require(:legislation).permit(:title, :attachment, {documents: []})
end
```

Model:

```
class Legislation < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :attachment, AttachmentUploader
    mount_uploaders :documents, DocumentUploader
    validates :title, presence: true
end
```

Migration:

```
class AddDocmentToLegislations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :legislations, :documents, :string, array: true, default: []
  end
end
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends of your Database Format:

If you have a database without ActiveRecord (e.g. SQLite), you have to add :

```
mount_uploaders :documents, DocumentUploader    
serialize :docuements, JSON # If you use SQLite, add this line.
```

If you have a database with ActiveRecord (e.g. PostgreSQL, MySQL), you just need to add :

```
mount_uploaders :documents, AvatarUploader
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the same question in official issue [here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/1653), and I solved problem

Just add `serialize :documents` to Model, and all question is gone